# how to delete elements of a string from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

For you this must be a really silly question for you but I'm new in this world of programming with python and I'm having some problems with lists.

I have this:

```
l=[['Pasta=3', 'Soup=2'],
 ['Soup=1', 'Fresh Vegetables=3', 'Milk=3', 'Plastic Utensils=2'],
 ['Cheese=2', 'Deodorizers=1', 'Hard Candy=2', 'Jam=2']]
```

wich list of lists.

I want to remove the '=' sign, as well as everything that is in front of it. But I still want to remain with a list os lists. So, what I want to be the final result is this:

```
l=[['Pasta', 'Soup'],
 ['Soup', 'Fresh Vegetables', 'Milk', 'Plastic Utensils'],
 ['Cheese', 'Deodorizers', 'Hard Candy', 'Jam']]
```

I've tryed a for cycle like this:

```
for i in h:
    for j in i:
        f=(j.replace('=',''))
```

But it didn't work.

Can I get some help?

Thanks

Comment: You should *really* look into using a dictionary

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the comments, you should *really* look into using a key: value dictionary object for this. But here's a solution:

```
>>> l=[['Pasta=3', 'Soup=2'],
...  ['Soup=1', 'Fresh Vegetables=3', 'Milk=3', 'Plastic Utensils=2'],
...  ['Cheese=2', 'Deodorizers=1', 'Hard Candy=2', 'Jam=2']]
>>> new_l = [[x[:x.find('=')] for x in y] for y in l]
>>> new_l
[['Pasta', 'Soup'], ['Soup', 'Fresh Vegetables', 'Milk', 'Plastic Utensils'], ['Cheese', 'Deodorizers', 'Hard Candy', 'Jam']]
```

Comment: You're totally right, bu for this Jupyter project I'm obligated to use only lists. Thank you very much for your solution :)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a reason as to why. I know `str.find` will return -1 when the element being searched for isn't present, which could cause trouble, but this solution completely satisfies the base case from above.